# How to use Java 8 `Files.find` method?

Tags: java, file-io, path, java-8

I am trying to write an app to use `Files.find` method in it.

Below program works perfectly :

```
package ehsan;

/* I have removed imports for code brevity */

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Path p = Paths.get("/home/ehsan");
        final int maxDepth = 10;
        Stream<Path> matches = Files.find(p,maxDepth,(path, basicFileAttributes) -> String.valueOf(path).endsWith(".txt"));
        matches.map(path -> path.getFileName()).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

This works fine and gives me a list of files ending with `.txt` ( aka text files ) :

```
hello.txt
...
```

But below program does not show anything :

```
package ehsan;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Path p = Paths.get("/home/ehsan");
        final int maxDepth = 10;
        Stream<Path> matches = Files.find(p,maxDepth,(path, basicFileAttributes) -> path.getFileName().equals("workspace"));
        matches.map(path -> path.getFileName()).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

But it does not show anything :(

Here is my home folder hiearchy (`ls` result) :

```
blog          Projects
Desktop       Public
Documents     Templates
Downloads     The.Purge.Election.Year.2016.HC.1080p.HDrip.ShAaNiG.mkv
IdeaProjects          The.Purge.Election.Year.2016.HC.1080p.HDrip.ShAaNiG.mkv.aria2
Music         Videos
Pictures      workspace
```

So whats going wrong with `path.getFileName().equals("workspace")`?

Comment: Have you tried to use a Debugger?

Comment: Beware that you must close the `Stream` that `Files.find(...)` returns, otherwise you have a resource leak; the [API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#find-java.nio.file.Path-int-java.util.function.BiPredicate-java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...-) explain this (see where it says "the try-with-resources construct should be used...").

Comment: IntelliJ has a very good debugger (I don't know what you mean with "VS debugger"). You can also just put `System.out.println(...)` statements at points in your code to see what is happening.

Comment: See [IntelliJ debugging documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/debugging.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Path.getFilename()` does not return a String, but a Path object, do this:

```
getFilename().toString().equals("workspace")
```

Comment: Thanks, Isn't it funny that getFileName() does not actually return file name !
?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following and look at the console. Maybe none of your files contains `workspace` in it

```
Files.find(p,maxDepth,(path, basicFileAttributes) -> {
    if (String.valueOf(path).equals("workspace")) {
        System.out.println("FOUND : " + path);
        return true;
    }
    System.out.println("\tNOT VALID : " + path);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: As shown in my Home directory hiearchy, I **HAVE** a `workspace` folder :)

Comment: Thanks, It was very useful and user friendly :)

Comment: @ehsan Youre welcome, I do not know if it is sarcasm but I wasn't being non friendly at all don't worry :) Hope it helped